# A martingale with uncorrelated components

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, martingales

Let $\zeta_{i}$ be a sequence of random variables such that the partial sums
\begin{align*}
X_{n}=\zeta_{0}+\zeta_{1}+\cdots+\zeta_{n},\quad n\geq 1,
\end{align*}
determine a martingale. Show that the summands are mutually uncorrelated, i.e. that $\mathbb {E}(\zeta_{i}\zeta_{j})=\mathbb {E}(\zeta_{i})\mathbb {E}(\zeta_{j})$ for $i\neq j$. I'm seeking for some hints to start with since I don't quite see what's the connection between the given condition and the conclusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that $X_0$ should also be defined as well, otherwise there would be no reason for $\zeta_0$ and $\zeta_1$ to be uncorrelated. (Let for example n=1 and $\zeta_1=\zeta_0$ be integrable correlated random variables. The $1$-step process $X$ is then clearly a martingale as it must only satisfy integrability.)

Let $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{0\leqslant i \leqslant n}$ be the corresponding filtration. First notice that $\mathbb{E}(\zeta_i)=0$ for $i\geqslant 1$, as, using tower property of conditional expectation and the Martingale property of $X_i$,
$$\mathbb{E}(\zeta_i)=\mathbb{E}(X_i-X_{i-1})=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_i-X_{i-1}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}))=0.$$

W.l.o.g. let $i<j$. Now the result directly follows as
$$ \mathbb{E}(\zeta_i \zeta_j)=\mathbb{E}(\zeta_i (X_j-X_{j-1}))=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\zeta_i (X_j-X_{j-1})|\mathbb{F}_i))=\mathbb{E}(\zeta_i \mathbb{E}(X_j-X_{j-1}|\mathbb{F}_i))=\mathbb{E}(\zeta_i (\mathbb{E}(X_j|\mathcal{F}_i)-\mathbb{E}(X_{j-1}|\mathcal{F}_i)))=\mathbb{E}(\zeta_i(X_i-X_i))=0.$$

Comment: How do you show that $\mathbb {E}\left(\zeta_{i}\mathbb {E}((X_{j}-X_{j-1})\vert \mathcal {F}_{i})\right)=0$? I have $\mathbb {E}\left(\zeta_{i}\mathbb {E}((X_{j}-X_{j-1})\vert \mathcal {F}_{i})\right)=\mathbb {E}\left(\zeta_{i}(X_{i}-\mathbb {E}(X_{i}))\right)=\mathbb {E}(\zeta_{i}X_{i})-\mathbb {E}(\zeta_{i})\mathbb {E}(X_{i})$.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it's clear now. Notice that by the martingale property it follows that $\mathbb{E}(X_{j-1}|\mathcal{F}_i)=\mathbb{E}(X_j|\mathcal{F}_i)=X_i$ for $j>i$.

Comment: What if $j-1=i$? Then $\mathbb {E}(X_{j-1}\vert \mathcal {F}_{i})=\mathbb {E}(X_{i}\vert \mathcal {F}_{i})=\mathbb {E}X_{i}\neq X_{i}$.

Comment: This is no problem. The equality you wrote is wrong. $X_i$ is $\mathcal{F}_i$ measurable and therefore $\mathbb{E}(X_i|\mathcal{F}_i)=X_i$, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation.